# Refresh of Zuul configuration when using Spring Config Service

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

We have a Zuul proxy (wraped with Spring Cloud/Boot) deployed that fetches configuration from the Spring Config Server. Every time I do changes in the routes I restart Zuul application and I wonder if there is a better approach that can be taken (like refresh of Zuul config information)? :)

Thank you,

Comment: This doc has a perfect explanation on what you need https://spencer.gibb.us/blog/2015/09/24/spring-cloud-config-push-notifications/

Answer (score 3):

You can issue a refresh command via rest:

`curl -X POST http://<host>:<port>/refresh`

I wrote a simple bash script that commits all my changes to the config file in the Git repository and then issue curl request to all my services.

If you wanted to be fancy you could write a script that first queries your `Eureka` server to get the list of all services and then refresh them all :)

Comment: If you wanted to be even more fancy you can use Spring Cloud Bus to propagate an `EnvironmentChangeEvent` to all of our applications connected.

Answer (score 1):

`Zuul` Routes could be dynamically refreshed when configuring them in a `Git` backend for instance, fronted by `Spring Cloud` Config server and `Spring Cloud Bus`.

I have covered this scenario in a recent blog post [Routing requests and dynamically refreshing routes using Spring Cloud Zuul Server](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/10/10/Routing-requests-and-dynamically-refreshing-routes-using-Spring-Cloud-Zuul-Server.html)

Answer (score 0):

For #1, Spring cloud config introduced the @RefreshScope annotation which will expose the /refresh endpoint (over HTTP or JMX)

For #2, after '/refresh', spring cloud config will take the latest git commit, For the config changes, essentially there are two ways, 1) pull the changes 2) push the changes, spring cloud bus approach is based on the rabbitmq to push the config changes.

[Check out this article](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/)

[And this also](https://www.devglan.com/spring-cloud/refresh-property-config-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Many respositories such as github are able to configure Webhook POST endpoints.

Besides the previously mentioned way of manually executing a request to the /refresh endpoint, you could configure your github config repository to use the /request endpoint as the webhook endpoint. That way, you could automatically refresh the properties on push.